# D3D11 Copy one texture into one half of the other

Tags: directx, textures, directx-11

I have a texture (size 1512x1680) that I would like to copy into the left half of my backbuffer (say in this case 920x540). Is there an easy way to do this?

CopySubresourceRegion can take a portion of my source texture, but it doesnt make it fit within my destination texture.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing easier than rendering a textured quad to draw the texture at the correct portion of the surface. But for such a simple thing, there is as many solutions as stars in the night sky, pick your favorite.

It has to involve a vertex shader and a pixel shader, that's the only constant. after that, how you setup everything else is up to your taste and convenience, can be with or without a source geometry, with or without a constant buffer, with or without a viewport tweak, etc.